# How to set datalist to show all options on focus?

Tags: html, html-datalist

I want to create a dropdown as in the snapshot below. I Googled and got to know that `HTML5 datalist` can help me do this. However, datalist does not show all options when the focus is on it. How do I show all options?

[image: Snapshot]

Here is my code so far:

```
<input list="theaters" name="theaters">
    <datalist id="theaters">
        <option value="Inox">
        <option value="E Square">
    </datalist>
</input>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your code by removing  closing tag

```
<input list="theaters" name="theaters">
<datalist id="theaters">
  <option value="Inox">
  <option value="E Square">
</datalist>
```

Check this [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Vtd/). Just press down arrow key when focused in textbox. It will show all options.

Comment: This works while having the closing tags on. Didnt knew the trick of down arrow key. Thanks!

Comment: this hack didn't work for me. (Editor error on enforcing to use the close tag)

Comment: @novonimo This is not a hack, its from HTML5 specification https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-input-element. Your editor thinks you are editing a xml or something like.

Comment: @RahulDesai Anyway the input should have no childs, the datalist is binded by the input's list attribute that corresponds to the list id attribute.